# Passing a value from a dropdown to eventListner

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

So I'm using AMCharts and I am trying to change the dataset from one set of data to another.

I'm using EventListner to call my function.

So in my html I have the following:

```
 <select id="data">
    <option value="set1">Institutional Design</option>
  <option value="set2">Effective </option>
  </select>
```

In my Javascript I have the following:

```
document.getElementById("data").addEventListener("change", selectDataset);


      function selectDataset(set) {
        var x = document.getElementById("data");
  x.value = data[set];
}

   // Add data
chart.data = data.set1;
```

So when the chart first loads it adds data.set1 as the chart data by default.  When I change it to Effectiveness (set2) all of the lines disappear.  Obviously I'm not passing on the value here.

Here is the Codepen: https://codepen.io/shopmaster/pen/GRZaewZ

Answer (score 0):

I believe event listeners automatically pass the event to the function, but selectDataset() is expecting an option value. Your variable `set` is actually the event, so you'll need to get the actual value out of the event's target.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

I needed to grab the value which I wasn't doing so here is how it should look:

```
document.getElementById("data").addEventListener("change", selectDataset);


      function selectDataset(set) {
        var set = document.getElementById("data").value;
  chart.data = data[set];
}
```